# Child object CreatedDate being set by Salesforce in past for some objects, older than Parent?

Tags: community

This is a very confusing matter to me. Salesforce is setting the CreatedDate for some child records to be older than that of a Parent CreatedDate, which isn't possible. A Purchase object cannot logically have a parent object on 09/06 when the Lead object was created on 11/06. Here's an example below. Moreover, I am not setting these dates anywhere in my code. CreatedDate is Salesforce timestamped.

**Sample Lead Object (parent)**
[image]

**Sample Purchase object (child)**
[image]

Comment: Do you have any data load processes running on these objects? It's possible to set the audit fields on creation if the org is configured to allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's (at least) a couple of reasons this could occur.

- If the relationship between Purchase and Lead permits reparenting, it may have been reparented from an older Lead.
- If the permission [Set Audit Fields on Record Creation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213290&type=1) is in use, any records created via the API by a user with that permission could potentially have had their creation date manually set.